# Connecting 2 houses via Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I posted this in [Network Engineering, and was directed to post it over here instead...](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/connecting-2-houses-via-wifi)

I'm trying to figure out exactly how I can get my and my neighbors home network setup as we want to... Here is a diagram that I hope can help:

[image: Homes Network]

So my house is on the left, and his is on the right.

The end goal is:
I'd like to be able to go to Computer 1, type in 192.168.1.100, and pull Computer 2 up, and I'd like him to be able to go Computer 2 to 192.168.0.100 and pull Computer 1 up.

I've had alot of suggestions to just setup a vpn tunnel, etc, but I am on a different ISP than him and we our internet is metered. If we can get this setup, we will not be subject to bandwidth limitations.

My router is 192.168.0.1 and my network operates off o the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet. His router is 192.168.1.1 and operates off of 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

I've tried setting up the ENS202EXT is Client Bridge and Client Router, however regardless of how I've tried to set this up, I can't get anything in House 1 to communicate to anything in House 2, or vice versa. I can get the Client bridge to connect to the router in house 2, (or atleast try.. it sends and receives packets), but won't get an IP or ping anything over there.

Has anyone done this? Does anyone have any guidance they can offer?

Comment: Wifi bridges typically operate at layer 2. You're on different subnets, and you'll need layer 3 (routing) between them. One way I can think of (probably not the best) would be to set up a machine connected to both networks to act as a router, and add it to the routing tables on the main gateway of each network.

Comment: That was what I was thinking too. I was going to connect the ENS202EXT to House 2, and have that connection go into a raspberry pi. I'd could hook up a USB ethernet cable to the pi, and setup routes. Any requests coming from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24, and vice versa, go through the ENS202EXT. I was just looking for different options as well. Maybe from someone who has used the ENS202EXT or can suggest a different device for me.